# r shiny - apply function to reactive data table

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, reactive

I would like to be able to apply a user defined function to the set of columns chosen via `pickerInput`.  I am unsure if I need an `actionButton` or not.

My code is below

```
X <- c("plyr", "dplyr", "tm", "readxl", "wordcloud", "SnowballC", "stringdist", "tidytext",
   "rmarkdown", "knitr", "quanteda", "reshape", "stringr", "RecordLinkage", 
   "data.table", "rvest", "qdap", "shiny", "shinydashboard", "shinyWidgets", "DT") 

lapply(X, FUN = function(X){
do.call("library", list(X))
})

###### BUILD REQUIRED FUNCTIONS TO CLEAN DATA ########

removeSPE <- function(x) gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)

cleanup <- function(x){
   x <- as.character(x) # convert to character
  x <- tolower(x) # make all lowercase
  x <- sapply(x, removeSPE) # remove special characters
  x <- trimws(x, "both") # since stopwords have been removed, there is extra white space left, this removes it
  x <- gsub("(?<=\\b\\w)\\s(?=\\w\\b)", "", x, perl = TRUE) # removes whitespace btwn two single chars
  return(x)
}
```

***UI***

```
##### APP BEGINS HERE WITH UI #####

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Record Linkage App"),
dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
        ## Tab 1 -- Specify Task
        menuItem("Select Task And Upload Files", tabName = "task", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
        ## Tab 2 -- View Raw Data Files
        menuItem("View Raw Data", tabName = "raw", icon = icon("file-excel")),
        ## Tab 3 -- View Processed Data Files
        menuItem("View Processed Data", tabName = "processed", icon = icon("file-excel")),
        ## Tab 4 -- Select Training Set
        menuItem("Select Training Set", tabName = "mltrain", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
        ## Tab 5 -- View Weight & Probabilities (choose which chart to view or both?)
        menuItem("Visualize Distributions", tabName = "distributions", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
        ## Tab 6 -- View Results (review, match and trash files--need to be able to choose dataset)
        ## Want to be able to add checkboxes to select rows for inclusion in deletion later on
        menuItem("View Result Files", tabName = "fileview", icon = icon("file-text-o"))

    )), # close dashboard sidebar

#### Dashboard Body starts here

dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        ### Specify Task & Upload Files Tab
        tabItem(tabName = "task",
                radioButtons("task", "Select a Task:", c("Frame Deduplication", "Frame Record Linkage")),
                fileInput("selection", "Upload Files:", multiple = T, 
                          accept = c(".xlsx", ".xls", "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain", ".csv")),
                helpText(paste("Please upload a file.  Supported file types are:  .txt, .csv and .xls.")),
                br(),
                helpText(paste("Note:  Record Linkage requires two data frames."))

        ), # close first tabItem

        tabItem(tabName = "raw",
                helpText(paste("This tab displays the raw, unprocessed data frames selected in the previous tab.")),
                helpText(paste("Select the columns you wish to display.  These columns will be used for string comparisons")),
                fluidRow(
                    column(width = 6,
                           uiOutput("pick_col1"),
                           dataTableOutput("content1")
                    ),
                    column(width = 6,
                           uiOutput("pick_col2"),
                           dataTableOutput("content2")
                    )
                )

        ), # close second tabItem

        tabItem(tabName = "processed",
                helpText(paste("This tab displays the processed data frames you saw in the previous tab.")),
                br(),
                helpText(paste("All data fields are now uniform and free of punctuation or special characters etc.")),
                actionButton("clean1", "Clean data from table 1"),
                actionbutton("clean2", "Clean data from table 2"),
                fluidRow(
                    column(width = 6,
                           uiOutput("clean_tbl1"),
                           dataTableOutput("clean_content1")
                    ),
                    column(width = 6,
                           uiOutput("clean_tbl2"),
                           dataTableOutput("clean_content1")
                    )
                )

        ) # close third tabItem
    ) # close tabItems
) # close dashboardBody 
) # closes dashboardpage

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
```

***SERVER***

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

data <- reactiveValues(file1 = NULL,
                       file2 = NULL)

observe({
    if (!is.null(input$selection$datapath[1]))

        if (grepl(".csv$", input$selection$datapath[1])) {

            data$file1 <- read.csv(input$selection$datapath[1], header = TRUE, sep = ",")

        } else if (grepl(".xls$|.xlsx$", input$selection$datapath[1])) {

            data$file1 <- read_excel(input$selection$datapath[1], col_names = TRUE)    
        } 
})

observe({
    if (!is.null(input$selection$datapath[2]))

        if (grepl(".csv$", input$selection$datapath[2])) {

            data$file2 <- read.csv(input$selection$datapath[2], header = TRUE, sep = ",")

        } else if (grepl(".xls$|.xlsx$", input$selection$datapath[2])) {

            data$file2 <- read_excel(input$selection$datapath[2], col_names = TRUE)    
        } 
})

output$pick_col1 <- renderUI({

    pickerInput(
        inputId = "pick_col1",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        choices = colnames(data$file1),
        selected = colnames(data$file1),
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                       `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(data$file1)) - 1),
                       `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
                       liveSearch = TRUE,
                       liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE),   # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE)
})

output$pick_col2 <- renderUI({

    pickerInput(
        inputId = "pick_col2",
        label = "Select the columns of table 2 you wish to display:",
        choices = colnames(data$file2),
        selected = colnames(data$file2),
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                       `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(data$file2)) - 1),
                       `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
                       liveSearch = TRUE,
                       liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE),   # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE)
})



output$content1 <- renderDataTable({

    data$file1[, req(input$pick_col1)]


})

output$content2 <- renderDataTable({

    data$file2[, req(input$pick_col2)]

})


# here we want to take the columns selected and apply our 
# pre defined functions:  sweet, etc. to make the data unform and easier to analyze.

observeEvent(input$clean1, {

    output$clean_content1 <- renderDataTable({
        cleanup(selection)


    })

})

observeEvent(input$clean2, {

    output$clean_content2 <- renderDataTable({
        cleanup(selection)

    })

})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My question is:

1. How can I apply a function `cleanup` defined above to the set of columns selected in the `pickerInput`?
2. Is an `actionButton` the best way to do so?
3. If I need to use the data I passed through the `cleanup` function, does making the datatable reactive inefficient?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. How can I apply a function cleanup defined above to the set of columns selected in the pickerInput?

**See example code bellow**

2. Is an actionButton the best way to do so?

**Really up to you**

3. If I need to use the data I passed through the cleanup function, does making the datatable reactive inefficient?

**Hard to say without knowing more about your data**

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

cleanup <- function(x) {
  mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}


ui <- basicPage(
  pickerInput(width = "75%",
    inputId = "pick_col1",
    label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
    choices = colnames(iris)[1:4],
    selected = colnames(iris)[1:4],
    options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE,
      `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(iris)) - 1),
      `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
      liveSearch = TRUE,
      liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
    ),
    # build buttons for collective selection
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  tags$hr(),
  column(width = 5, h2("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data")),
  column(width = 1),
  column(
    width = 5,
    h2("Processed selected columns"),
    actionButton("cleanup", "Clean up"),
    tableOutput("mean_data")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
# show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data <- renderTable({
    iris %>% select(Species, input$pick_col1) %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      top_n(n = 2)
  })

# button to run the processing function. 
# In this case just get the mean per Iris species
# make it just reactive (or include inside renderTable below) 
# if actionButton is not desired
  clean_df <- eventReactive(input$cleanup, {
    iris %>% select(Species, input$pick_col1) %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      summarise_all(.funs =list(cleanup))
  })

# show the processed columns  
  output$mean_data <- renderTable({
    clean_df()
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT: Two tables in two tabs with two input pickers, no action buttons**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

cleanup <- function(x) {
  mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

ui <- basicPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "tabs",
  tabPanel(
    title = "Table 1",
    value = "tab1",
    wellPanel(
      pickerInput(
        width = "75%",
        inputId = "pick_col1",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        choices = colnames(iris)[1:4],
        selected = colnames(iris)[1:4],
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(iris)) - 1),
          `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
          liveSearch = TRUE,
          liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
        ),
        # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    wellPanel(h4("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data1")),
    wellPanel(h4("Processed selected columns"), tableOutput("mean_data1"))
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Table 2",
    value = "tab2",
    wellPanel(
      pickerInput(
        width = "75%",
        inputId = "pick_col2",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        choices = colnames(mtcars),
        selected = colnames(mtcars),
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(mtcars)) - 1),
          `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
          liveSearch = TRUE,
          liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
        ),
        # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    wellPanel(h4("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data2")),
    wellPanel(h4("Processed selected columns"), tableOutput("mean_data2"))
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  # show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data1 <- renderTable({
    iris %>% select(Species, input$pick_col1) %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      top_n(n = 2)
  })

  # show the processed columns
  output$mean_data1 <- renderTable({
    iris %>% select(Species, input$pick_col1) %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise_all(.funs = list(cleanup))
  })

  # show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data2 <- renderTable({
    mtcars %>%  mutate("Car" = rownames(.)) %>%
      select(Car, input$pick_col2) %>%
      group_by(cyl) %>%
      top_n(n = 2)
  })

  # show the processed columns
  output$mean_data2 <- renderTable({
    mtcars %>% mutate("Car" = rownames(.)) %>%
      select(Car, input$pick_col2) %>%
      group_by(cyl) %>%
      summarise_all(.funs = list(cleanup))
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT 2: same table in both tabs, same reactives that process the table, but they respond to different inputs based on the active tab: **

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

cleanup <- function(x) {
  mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

ui <- basicPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "tabs",
  tabPanel(
    title = "Table 1",
    value = "tab1",
    wellPanel(
      pickerInput(
        width = "75%",
        inputId = "pick_col1",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        choices = colnames(iris)[1:4],
        selected = colnames(iris)[1:4],
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(iris)) - 1),
          `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
          liveSearch = TRUE,
          liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
        ),
        # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    wellPanel(h4("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data1")),
    wellPanel(h4("Processed selected columns"), tableOutput("mean_data1"))
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Table 2",
    value = "tab2",
    wellPanel(
      pickerInput(
        width = "75%",
        inputId = "pick_col2",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        choices = colnames(iris)[1:4],
        selected = colnames(iris)[1:4],
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(iris)) - 1),
          `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
          liveSearch = TRUE,
          liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
        ),
        # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    wellPanel(h4("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data2")),
    wellPanel(h4("Processed selected columns"), tableOutput("mean_data2"))
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # decide what to render based on the selected tab
  respond_to_tab <- reactive({
    if (input$tabs == "tab1") {
      selected_columns <- input$pick_col1
    } else {
      selected_columns <- input$pick_col2
    }
    return(selected_columns)
  })

  raw_data <- reactive({
    iris %>% select(Species, respond_to_tab()) %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      top_n(n = 2)
  })

  mean_data <- reactive({
    iris %>% select(Species, respond_to_tab()) %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise_all(.funs = list(cleanup))
  })

  # show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data1 <- renderTable({
    raw_data()
  })

  # show the processed columns
  output$mean_data1 <- renderTable({
    mean_data()
  })

  # show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data2 <- renderTable({
    raw_data()
  })

  # show the processed columns
  output$mean_data2 <- renderTable({
    mean_data()
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT 3: pickers rendered through `renderUI` dependent on tables selected by user. Otherwise works as EDIT 2. Note also some new packages are loaded.**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
library(readr)

cleanup <- function(x) {
  mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

ui <- basicPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "tabs",
  tabPanel(
    title = "File input",
    value = "input",
    fileInput(
      "selection",
      "Upload Files:",
      multiple = T,
      accept = c(
        ".xlsx",
        ".xls",
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain",
        ".csv"
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Table 1",
    value = "tab1",
    uiOutput("picker1"),
    wellPanel(h4("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data1")),
    wellPanel(h4("Processed selected columns"), tableOutput("mean_data1"))
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Table 2",
    value = "tab2",
    uiOutput("picker2"),
    wellPanel(h4("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data2")),
    wellPanel(h4("Processed selected columns"), tableOutput("mean_data2"))
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # handle the file import
  read_input_file <- function(filepath) {
    if (str_detect(filepath, regex(".csv$"))) {
      out <- read_csv(filepath)
    }

    if (str_detect(filepath, regex(".xls$|.xlsx$"))) {
      out <- read_excel(filepath)
    }
    return(out)
  }

  file1 <- reactive({
    read_input_file(input$selection$datapath[1])
  })

  file2 <- reactive({
    read_input_file(input$selection$datapath[2])
  })

  # pickers reactive to user input file
  output$picker1 <- renderUI({
    wellPanel(
      pickerInput(
        width = "75%",
        inputId = "pick_col1",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        # still using iris (loaded from file), so 1:4 makes sense for the rest of the app logic
        choices = colnames(file1())[1:4], 
        selected = colnames(file1())[1:4],
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(iris)) - 1),
          `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
          liveSearch = TRUE,
          liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
        ),
        # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  output$picker2 <- renderUI({
    wellPanel(
      pickerInput(
        width = "75%",
        inputId = "pick_col2",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        choices = colnames(file2())[1:4],
        selected = colnames(file2())[1:4],
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(iris)) - 1),
          `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
          liveSearch = TRUE,
          liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
        ),
        # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  # decide what to render based on the selected tab
  respond_to_tab <- reactive({
    if (input$tabs == "tab1") {
      selected_columns <- input$pick_col1
    } else {
      selected_columns <- input$pick_col2
    }
    return(selected_columns)
  })

  raw_data <- reactive({
    iris %>% select(Species, respond_to_tab()) %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      top_n(n = 2)
  })

  mean_data <- reactive({
    iris %>% select(Species, respond_to_tab()) %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise_all(.funs = list(cleanup))
  })

  # show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data1 <- renderTable({
    raw_data()
  })

  # show the processed columns
  output$mean_data1 <- renderTable({
    mean_data()
  })

  # show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data2 <- renderTable({
    raw_data()
  })

  # show the processed columns
  output$mean_data2 <- renderTable({
    mean_data()
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Another EDIT. Aside from the fixes related to iris, this code has another `reactive` to deal with which dataset to process based on the active tab.**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
library(readr)

# not used in this version 
# it depends on the loaded datasets...
# need to define the function based on the expected input

cleanup <- function(x) {
  mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

ui <- basicPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "tabs",
  tabPanel(
    title = "File input",
    value = "input",
    fileInput(
      "selection",
      "Upload Files:",
      multiple = T,
      accept = c(
        ".xlsx",
        ".xls",
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain",
        ".csv"
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Table 1",
    value = "tab1",
    uiOutput("picker1"),
    wellPanel(h4("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data1")),
    wellPanel(h4("Processed selected columns"), tableOutput("mean_data1"))
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Table 2",
    value = "tab2",
    uiOutput("picker2"),
    wellPanel(h4("Selected columns"), tableOutput("raw_data2")),
    wellPanel(h4("Processed selected columns"), tableOutput("mean_data2"))
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # handle the file import
  read_input_file <- function(filepath) {
    if (str_detect(filepath, regex(".csv$"))) {
      out <- read_csv(filepath)
    }

    if (str_detect(filepath, regex(".xls$|.xlsx$"))) {
      out <- read_excel(filepath)
    }
    return(out)
  }

  file1 <- reactive({
    read_input_file(input$selection$datapath[1])
  })

  file2 <- reactive({
    read_input_file(input$selection$datapath[2])
  })

  # pickers reactive to user input file
  output$picker1 <- renderUI({
    wellPanel(
      pickerInput(
        width = "75%",
        inputId = "pick_col1",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        # still using iris (loaded from file), so 1:4 makes sense for the rest of the app logic
        choices = colnames(file1()), 
        selected = colnames(file1()),
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(file1())) - 1),
          `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
          liveSearch = TRUE,
          liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
        ),
        # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  output$picker2 <- renderUI({
    wellPanel(
      pickerInput(
        width = "75%",
        inputId = "pick_col2",
        label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
        choices = colnames(file2()),
        selected = colnames(file2()),
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(file2())) - 1),
          `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
          liveSearch = TRUE,
          liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE
        ),
        # build buttons for collective selection
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  # decide what columns to render based on the selected tab
  respond_to_tab <- reactive({
    if (input$tabs == "tab1") {
      selected_columns <- input$pick_col1
    } else {
      selected_columns <- input$pick_col2
    }
    return(selected_columns)
  })
# decide what table to work with based on the selected tab
  respond_to_tab_data <- reactive({
    if (input$tabs == "tab1") {
      x <- file1()
    } else {
      x <- file2()
    }
    return(x)
  })


  raw_data <- reactive({
    respond_to_tab_data() %>% select(respond_to_tab()) %>%
      head()
  })

  mean_data <- reactive({
    respond_to_tab_data() %>% select(respond_to_tab()) %>%
      tail()
  })

  # show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data1 <- renderTable({
    raw_data()
  })

  # show the processed columns
  output$mean_data1 <- renderTable({
    mean_data()
  })

  # show the selected columns (plus the grouping variable)
  output$raw_data2 <- renderTable({
    raw_data()
  })

  # show the processed columns
  output$mean_data2 <- renderTable({
    mean_data()
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is good, but I'm not sure if it works with my code above because the whole point is there may be two tables depending on what the user uploads.  With two tables, there wouldn't be room on the page for four tables.  I was thinking an `actionButton` in a new tab--hence the dashboard layout.

Comment: See the edits for one way you could deal with two tables and two input pickers in two tabs. This is easily adaptable into a dashboard layout, maybe the tabs become sidebar menus, or collapsible boxes (or they stay tabs). Your app will probably be more complicated than this, of course, all these are just examples.

Comment: Notice also that the code to select columns and render tables is essentially the same, with only the input/output ids changing. This is a perfect situation to implement a module: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: OK, I see...just fyi though:  the same dataset should be used for both tabs.  Thanks for this though.  I see your point

Comment: Right, see another quick edit. Same table, same processing functions, but the decision which inputs to process is made based on the active tab.

Comment: why is the `pickerInput` in the `ui` and not `server`?

Comment: I am not sure one needs to render the `pickerInput` through the server unless the its reactive to some other component of the app (like different tables selected by user).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. In your case, where the user is selecting the tables, `renderUI` is required. So the pickers should go to the server. My examples were not using file input, so the pickers could be defined in the ui.

Comment: yes, that's where I keep getting hung up.  I want to keep the `renderUI` but apply the function after `pickerInput` is processed.  Not quite sure how to modify to fit.  Tried your method with `select` etc at the end of my `server` and I get `incorrect number of dimensions` error.

Comment: OK. See if edit #3 above gets you closer to the desired behavior. This time the pickers are rendered reactively based on the tables selected by the user. The processing of the tables after picking columns still works the same.

Comment: There is an error produced because you are still using `iris` and not `input$pick_col1`? On the server side.

Comment: Sorry about the `iris` thing. I just wanted to show how you can deal with the two tables, so on my end I tested with `iris` being loaded twice. But that hid a problem with the reactivity. See my last edit where all this should be fixed.